# PHP7 PDO_DBLIB uniqueidentifier

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, uniqueidentifier

I'm  currently using the `pdo_dblib` extension in my project.
When I use this under `PHP 5.6` with `FreeTDS Version 7.0` set in `config.` It will give me the uniqueidentifier as `string`.
When i use the same script under `PHP 7.0.8` it just gives me out some garbled shit.
I don't wanna cast it in the `SQL` or convert it later in `PHP`. Because sometimes it can be a uniqueidentifier in the result and sometimes not. so i would need to go through the complete results to convert the uniqueidentifier.

So is there any solution to get in work on `PHP 7.0.8` like it was under `PHP 5.6`?

Comment: What is your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bug was introduced in some minor version of PHP7.

- 7.0.4 works perfectly. You can manually compile it with phpbrew.
- 7.0.8 has this implementation currently broken.

There was already a bug report filed for this issue here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72601

and a pull request for a potential fix:
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/2001

Add the following flag to your \PDO instance

```
/** @var \PDO $pdo */
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the pull request mentioned in Bojan's answer, the cause of this issue in PHP 7 is that you have to instruct PDO to convert the GUIDs from binary to a string.

This should do it for anyone struggling with this.

```
    /** @var \PDO $pdo */
    $pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, true);
```

Comment: That really did the trick. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.

Comment: where do i need to add this?